# How to get ip adress on centOS VM

Tags: centos, ip

I've been given a CentOS virtual machine which contains an Oracle database and no graphical interface. I'm pretty new to Linux and I just now nothing specific to CentOS. I'm trying to retrieve the IP adress of my virtual machine in order to connect to the database from my computer (outside of the VM).

At the moment, I've tried to run `ip addr` in the console of the VM, which returned me (can't copy paste on the VM so i'm just giving the inet) `127.0.0.1/8`,
which is obviously not what I'm looking for. I also tried this line from my terminal (not the one in the VM):

```
VBoxManage guestproperty get OracleXE "/VirtualBox/GuestInfo/Net/0/V4/IP"
```

Which returned me: `Value is not set !` (I tried ending the path with `/1/V4/IP`, and both 0 and 1 for V6, with the same result.)

So I'm out of ideas and can't find how to retrieve the IP adress. How can I get it on a CentOS VM? I'm using VirtualBox but can also use vmWare if that can help.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you don't have any network interfaces configured. Have a look at the [VirtualBox manual, especially chapter 6,](https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch06.html) on how to configure network interfaces.

If the virtual machine is on your PC, I would suggest to configure a `host-only network`. In case the virtual machine is on another PC on your network or it needs to be accessible from another computer in your network, then I suggest configuring `Bridged networking`.